# При комплиляции программа выдает a=0.00000,b=-9334555

Tags: c++, visual-c++

уважаемые форумчане. Пишу программу по заданию(Даны 2 числа. Если они оба отрицательны, то первое уменьшить на 1, а второе увеличить на 1; если оба положительны, то большее из них удвоить, а меньшее утроить; в противном случае отрицательное из чисел заменить его абсолютным значением.). Но при компиляции программа мне выводит a=0.00000,и=-9673644... ; Дайте пожалуйста рекомендацию, где же я мог накосячить при написании программы. Прикладываю код.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    float a, b,c;
    printf("vvedite a \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &a);
    printf("vvedite b \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &b);

    if (a&&b < 0)
    {
        a -= 1;
        b += 1;
    }
    if (a&&b > 0)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            a = a * 2;
            b = a * 3;
        }
        if (b > a)
        {
            b = b * 2;
            a = a * 3;
        }
        if (a&&b == 0)
        {
            a = fabs(a);
            b = fabs(b);
        }

        printf("a = %lf, b = %lf \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &c);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Именно при компиляции выводит? 8-0 И скажите - что, по-вашему, должно давать вот это выражение - `a&&b < 0` (ну, и аналогичные)? И у вас точно должны быть числа с плавающей точкой?

Comment: `a&&b` - это работает не так, как вы полагаете.

Comment: При вводе значения (а) = 1, (b) = 1, выводит a= 0.000000, b= -925595922941216....

Comment: Я понимаю, что я тут неправильно написал.

Comment: Еще раз - что вы хотели получить, написав `a&&b < 0`?

Comment: То есть не кого не смущает, что в коде используется стандартная библиотека `c++` `iostream`, и `c-ишный` ввод и вывод?

Comment: Что-то у вас b каждый раз разное число выводит. Определитесь уже.

Answer (score 2):

Вы получаете неопределенный результат, поскольку:

```
 printf("a = %lf, b = %lf \n");
```

должен выводить два аргумента  тип float, но вы их не передаете. Исправьте на:

```
printf("a = %lf, b = %lf \n", a, b);
```

А также закрывющую скобку тела if нужно поставить перед   `return 0;` а не после.

И после исправления этих ошибок ваша программа  не выполнит то, что вы ожидаете, потому что вы проверки условый выполняете неверно.

Comment: только `%lf` для `double`, а для `float` у нас вроде `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, нужно исправить вывод. Правильно будет так:
`printf("a = %f, b = %f \n", a, b);`

Во-вторых, исправить проверки в условиях. Когда сравниваете несколько чисел с константой, нужно делать это не сразу одним условием, а сравнивать каждое число отдельно, объединяя их логическими связками. Например,

```
if (a<0.0 && b<0.0) ... // Если оба отрицательны
if (a>0.0 && b>0.0) ... // Если оба положительны
```

В-третьих, раз уж пользуетесь идеологически-чистым вводом-выводом, нужно взять заголовочный файл `stdio.h` вместо `iostream`, и потом `using namespace std` уже не нужен.

В-четвёртых, вместо `scanf_s` надо использовать `scanf`, если не знаете, в чём разница. А вы не знаете, это видно по коду.

В-пятых, нужно вынести вывод данных и выход из функции ЗА пределы последнего `if`.

*>> где же я мог накосячить при написании программы*

Везде :)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение))

Comment: И при вводе scanf, у меня компилятор выводил ошибку,что scanf  не безопасная функция ,нужно вводить scanf_s

Comment: В таком случае, вам следует прочитать документацию по `scanf_s` и увидеть, что вы её неправильно используете, у неё должен быть третий параметр, обозначающий размер блока данных.